# Scroll loop infinito automático en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dispongo del siguiente script que aplico a la lista de elementos, "#contain":

```js
var time;
$(document).ready(function() {
  pageScroll();
  $("#contain").mouseover(function() {
clearTimeout(time);
  }).mouseout(function() {
pageScroll();
  });
});


function pageScroll() {
 var objDiv = document.getElementById("contain");
  objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollTop + 1;
  if (objDiv.scrollTop == (objDiv.scrollHeight - 625)) {
      objDiv.scrollTop = 0;
  }
time = setTimeout('pageScroll()', 100);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="contain">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Con él consigo un scroll en el que, cuando finaliza el recorrido de elementos, éste se repite pero la parte superior vuelve a comenzar posicionada desde arriba (el primer elemento de la lista "#contain" siempre está arriba).

Me gustaría conseguir un efecto en el que la parte superior de "#contain" apareciera desde abajo (algo así como un append loop) en un lazo infinito completo, es decir, cuando el último elemento, por ejemplo, de una lista contenida en "#contain" desaparece por arriba, el primer elemento de la lista aparece desde abajo.

¿Existe algún método que me ayude en mi propósito?¿alguna pista para una función?

Comment: Intentas hacer una especie de slider infinito vertical?

Comment: Básicamente sí, pero los elementos son filas de texto devueltas por una consulta php a mysql. Quiero que la primera fila se concatene de nuevo tras la última fila. He intentado realizar un append del elemento <ul> sobre sí mismo pero no encuentro el modo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He resuelto mi problema añadiendo una función append_clone() que clona cada elemento de la lista y lo agrega al final de "#contain", de este modo el scroll se hace infinito.

```js
var time;
$(document).ready(function(){
  append_clone();
  pageScroll();
});

function append_clone(){
  $("#contain li").each(function(){
    $("#contain li").clone().appendTo("#contain");
  });
}

function pageScroll() {
  var objDiv = document.getElementById("contain");
  objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollTop + 1;
  time = setTimeout('pageScroll()', 100);
}
```

```css
#contain {
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#contain li {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="contain">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Excelente! me alegra que pudieras encontrar la solución.